# I'm getting problems with vue.js with npm install it gives me these errors

Tags: vue.js

> I ran NPM install clean and other stuff listed below this code.

```
  ajv  <6.12.3
  Severity: moderate
  Prototype Pollution in Ajv - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-v88g-cgmw-v5xw
  fix available via `npm audit fix`
  node_modules/schema-utils/node_modules/ajv
    schema-utils  <=0.4.3
    Depends on vulnerable versions of ajv
    node_modules/schema-utils
      extract-text-webpack-plugin  2.1.1 - 3.0.2
      Depends on vulnerable versions of schema-utils
      node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin
  
  json5  <1.0.2
  Severity: high
  Prototype Pollution in JSON5 via Parse Method - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-9c47-m6qq-7p4h
  fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
  Will install babel-core@4.7.16, which is a breaking change
  node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/json5
    babel-core  5.8.20 - 7.0.0-beta.3
    Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-register
    Depends on vulnerable versions of json5
    node_modules/babel-core
      babel-register  *
      Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-core
      node_modules/babel-register
  
  nth-check  <2.0.1
  Severity: high
  Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-rp65-9cf3-cjxr
  fix available via `npm audit fix`
  node_modules/svgo/node_modules/nth-check
    css-select  <=3.1.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of nth-check
    node_modules/svgo/node_modules/css-select
      svgo  1.0.0 - 1.3.2
      Depends on vulnerable versions of css-select
      node_modules/svgo
        postcss-svgo  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 5.0.0-rc.2
        Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
        node_modules/postcss-svgo
          cssnano-preset-default  <=4.0.8
          Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-svgo
          node_modules/cssnano-preset-default
            cssnano  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.1.11
            Depends on vulnerable versions of cssnano-preset-default
            node_modules/cssnano
              optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin  3.2.1 || 5.0.0 - 5.0.8
              Depends on vulnerable versions of cssnano
              node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin
  
  serialize-javascript  <=3.0.0
  Severity: high
  Cross-Site Scripting in serialize-javascript - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-h9rv-jmmf-4pgx
  Insecure serialization leading to RCE in serialize-javascript - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-hxcc-f52p-wc94
  fix available via `npm audit fix`
  node_modules/copy-webpack-plugin/node_modules/serialize-javascript
  node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/node_modules/serialize-javascript
    copy-webpack-plugin  4.3.0 - 5.1.1
    Depends on vulnerable versions of cacache
    Depends on vulnerable versions of serialize-javascript
    node_modules/copy-webpack-plugin
    uglifyjs-webpack-plugin  >=1.1.3
    Depends on vulnerable versions of cacache
    Depends on vulnerable versions of serialize-javascript
    node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
  
  ssri  5.2.2 - 6.0.1
  Severity: high
  Regular Expression Denial of Service (ReDoS) - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-vx3p-948g-6vhq
  fix available via `npm audit fix`
  node_modules/cacache/node_modules/ssri
    cacache  10.0.4 - 11.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of ssri
    node_modules/cacache
  
  18 vulnerabilities (3 moderate, 15 high)
```

> I've tried everything npm audit fix doesn't work, npm audit fix -->force doesn't work tried updating the whole package and followed >multiple tutorials even tried clearing the cache and it didn't fix >itself so I'm clueless at this point anybody got any suggestions? cuz I'm stuck.

Comment: remove node_modules folder and package-lock.json files. then use yarn or pnpm. run pnpm install for installation. npm has these problems, so use a newer package manager.

Comment: Is this solution a must or does it have any other solutions cuz I'm doing a course that requires npm or using yarn or pnpm is the same thing as npm cuz I dont want it interfering with my project

Comment: As I know, my dear friend, these options are change able. With out serious problems, you can use yarn or pnpm. just remove package-lock.json file, node_modules folder, and run pnpm install (consider installing pnpm, if you don't from https://pnpm.io/installation which is pretty straight forward)